# Infinite 301 redirects on 2 sites

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

I have two websites:

1. http://forkandspoon.pl/ - Worpress
2. http://lunch.forkandspoon.pl/ - custom code (old Kohana framework)

Not sure what happened but everything was working fine until a few days ago. The sites are no longer accessible. There is an infinite number of 301 redirects.
**Site 1** - Weird part is, admin panel is accessible and is working but the main website isn't. Wordpress is updated to the latest version, I did update plugins and themes but I have not done any development.
I disabled all plugins, switched to a different theme, deleted .htaccess file (which is standard, no weird code in there). Nothing helps.
**Site 2** - I have not touched this site in months.

I went through the code for both sites, I compared the code from server with local copies. Everything looks to be in order.
I have Apache and Nginx on that server and the configuration has not changed at all. I have other websites hosted on the same server and they're not affected.
Cloudflare handles DNS, which I also checked and everything looks fine there.

What can be happening here? I'm out of ideas. Any clues?

As requested, here's Nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/forkandspoon/forkandspoon.pl;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name forkandspoon.pl www.forkandspoon.pl;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/forkandspoon/lunch.forkandspoon.pl;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name lunch.forkandspoon.pl www.lunch.forkandspoon.pl;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

and Apache

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin myemail@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/forkandspoon/forkandspoon.pl/
    ServerName forkandspoon.pl
    ServerAlias www.forkandspoon.pl
    ErrorLog logs/forkandspoon.pl-error_log
    CustomLog logs/forkandspoon.pl-access_log common
    <Directory /home/forkandspoon/forkandspoon.pl>
        Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin myemail@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/forkandspoon/lunch.forkandspoon.pl/
    ServerName lunch.forkandspoon.pl
    ServerAlias www.lunch.forkandspoon.pl
    ErrorLog logs/lunch.forkandspoon.pl-error_log
    CustomLog logs/lunch.forkandspoon.pl-access_log common
    <Directory /home/forkandspoon/lunch.forkandspoon.pl>
        Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note,
I also disabled Cloudflare proxy as per one of the comments. It may take a few minutes to take effect.

Comment: have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: If by this very helpful comment you mean restarting Apache and Nginx, then yes I did.

Comment: It looks like CloudFlare is also proxying the site(s)? The IP-numbers `forkandspoon.pl` resolves to (`104.28.1{8,9}.34`) are owned by CloudFlare.

Comment: We would really need to see apache and nginx conf files

Comment: @DusanBajic just updated main question

Comment: Is your server's IP address 188.165.222.229?

Comment: @DusanBajic Yes that's my server's IP

Comment: run on server `curl --verbose --header 'Host: forkandspoon.pl' 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/'` to see if redirect is coming from apache. If it is (since it is not form .conf file) it has to be from .htaccess or from php

Comment: that curl returned proper HTML so it's not redirecting

Comment: as a quick fix, try changing in nginx.conf line 14: `proxy_set_header Host forkandspoon.pl;` and see if it helps

Comment: @DusanBajic changed it as you suggested, restarted nginx, no change

Comment: I am confused now. Can you try this curl (the redirect is definitely coming from PHP, there is `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.25` in response):  `curl --verbose --header 'Host: forkandspoon.pl' 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.php'`

Comment: @DusanBajic that gives the 301 redirect, does it mean it comes somewhere from php?

Comment: Definitely, from index.php (also, you can revert that header change in nginx, it was a long shot). Maybe try at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DusanBajic I'll try asking there. Thank you. The weird thing is, why is my other site also affected. It's not wordpress.

Comment: well, lunch is not redirecting me, but it does show some weird error

Comment: @DusanBajic I figured it out for Wordpress. Seems to be a known issue when the home page is a static page https://wordpress.org/support/topic/45-causes-infinite-redirect-on-static-front-page/

Comment: @DusanBajic You pointed me in the right direction. Thank you. Do you want to give an answer below so that I can accept and you get credit for it?

Comment: No, I can't, it is not my answer really :), but it is perfectly fine that you answer your own question, it might help someone in the future

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out this is a know issue https://wordpress.org/support/topic/45-causes-infinite-redirect-on-static-front-page/ apparently introduced in Wordpress 4.5 where if your homepage is a static page you'll be infinitely redirected.
The fix for that can be found in the above link.

Thank you to @DusanBajic for pointing me in the right direction :)